# double free error when freeing a single pointer

Tags: c, list, valgrind

I'm doing this college assignment where I have to read information about a maze and store it in a struct, and since a single file can contain multiple mazes, each maze is linked to each other through a list. However, I'm getting some weird errors, mainly a double free when trying to free a single pointer.

The information within each maze struct is not so important in this context, where I'm having problems is in the linked list in itself.

Here is the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* filePtr;
    LabList* head = NULL;

    //if (DEBUG) printStrArray(argc, argv, "cmdln args");

    if (argc != 3) {
         printf("Numero de argumentos errado! \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char flag[] = "-s";

    if ( strcmp(argv[1], flag) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Flag '-s' necessária para esta fase do projeto!"); //verifica se a flag -s está presente
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *file_arg /*argumento indicado no terminal para referir ao ficheiro*/, *filename /*nome "próprio" do ficheiro*/, *file_arg_aux;
    char dot = '.';
    char ponto[] = ".";
    char *extencao;
    char extencao_out[] = ".sol1";
    int read_ok; 

    file_arg = (char*)calloc(1, strlen(argv[2]) + strlen(extencao_out) + 1); //verifica se de facto a extensão é .in1
    file_arg_aux = (char*) calloc(1, strlen(argv[2]) +1 );
    strcpy(file_arg, argv[2]);
    strcpy(file_arg_aux, argv[2]);
    filename = (char*)calloc(1, strlen(file_arg) + strlen(ponto) + 1);
    filename = strtok(file_arg, ponto);
    extencao = strrchr(file_arg_aux, dot);

    if ((read_ok = strcmp(extencao, ".in1")) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Extensão inválida!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    filePtr = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    if (filePtr == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro %s !\n", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        head = readLab(filePtr, head);
        fclose(filePtr);
    }

    FILE* file_out = fopen( strcat(filename, extencao_out) , "w");

    LabList* aux;
    aux = head;
```

roap.c file with functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "roap.h"

LabList* newLabList(Labirinto* m) {
    LabList* newML = calloc(1, sizeof(LabList) );
    checkAllocationError(newML, "Error allocating labList");

    newML->lab = m;
    newML->next = NULL;

    return newML;
}



LabList* addLab(LabList* head, LabList* ML, Labirinto* m) {
    ML = newLabList(m);
    LabList* aux;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = ML;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = head;
        while (aux-> next != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux-> next;
        }
    aux-> next = ML;
    ML-> lab = m;
    }

    return head;
}



void checkAllocationError(const void* ptr, const char* errorMsg) {
    if ( ! ptr ) {
        printf("\n%s\n", errorMsg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}



Labirinto* inputLab(FILE* filePtr) {
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    int lines, cols, celLine, celCol;

    int conversions = fscanf(filePtr, "%d %d %d %d",
        &lines, &cols, &celLine, &celCol);

    if( conversions != 4 ) {    // EOF
        printf("\n EOF with conversions=%d \n", conversions);
        return NULL;
    }

    Labirinto* m = calloc(1, sizeof(Labirinto) );
    checkAllocationError(m, "Erro ao alocar labirinto! m");

    m->L= lines;
    m->C = cols;
    m->cel_L = celLine;
    m->cel_C = celCol;

    printf("conversions:%d \n size: %d %d treasure: %d %d \n",
        conversions, m->L, m->C, m->cel_L, m->cel_C);

    conversions = fscanf(filePtr, "%s", buffer);

    printf("conversions:%d buffer=[%s] \n", conversions, buffer);

    if (buffer[0]=='A') {
        m->modo = buffer[1]-'0';
        if (m->modo == 6) {
            conversions = fscanf(filePtr, "%d %d", &m->cel_2_L, &m->cel_2_C);
            printf("conversions:%d \n same room? %d %d \n",
                                conversions, m->cel_2_L, m->cel_2_C);
        }
        conversions = fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &m->P);
    } else {
        m->modo = 0;
        buffer[BUFFERSIZE-1] = '\0';
        conversions = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &m->P);
    }

    printf("conversions: %d \n modo=%d P=%d \n",
                       conversions, m->modo, m->P);

    m->paredes = calloc(m->P, sizeof(Parede));
    checkAllocationError(m-> paredes, "Erro ao alocar paredes");

    for(int i=0; i<m->P; i++) {
        conversions = fscanf(filePtr, "%d %d %d", &m->paredes[i].line,
                           &m->paredes[i].col, &m->paredes[i].cost);

        printf("conversions: %d \n parede: %d %d %d \n",
                       conversions, m->paredes[i].line,
                       m->paredes[i].col, m->paredes[i].cost);
    }

    //printf("\n===================================\n");

    return m;
}




LabList* readLab(FILE* filePtr, LabList *head) {

    LabList* nextLabList = head;

    while( !feof(filePtr) ) {
        Labirinto* m = inputLab(filePtr);
        if (m) {
            addLab(head, nextLabList, m);
            //showLab(m);
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void freelist(LabList* head)
{
    LabList* aux;

    aux = head;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        aux = head;
        head = head-> next;
        for (int i = 0; i < aux-> lab->P; i++)
        {
            free(aux->lab->paredes);
        }
        free (aux->lab);
        free (aux);
    }
}
```

Header file with data structures:

```
#ifndef ROAP
#define ROAP

#include <stdio.h>

//#define DEBUG      1
#define BUFFERSIZE 5

typedef struct Parede {
    /* ints Li e Ci da localizacao, int Vi (−1:negra, int>0:custo) */
    int line, col, cost;
} Parede;

typedef struct Labirinto {
    /* dimensao do labirinto ints L e C */
    /* ints Lt e Ct das coordenadas do ponto de chegada */
    /* int P celulas negras/cinzentas */
    int L, C, cel_L, cel_C, P;
    int modo;           // 1..6
    int cel_2_L, cel_2_C;         // same room test coords
    Parede* paredes;
} Labirinto;

/* Strictly has just one maze, however it also iterates the maze list */
typedef struct LabList {
    Labirinto* lab;
    struct LabList* next;
} LabList;

/* creates a MazeList item ready to be inserted in a list of mazes */
LabList* newLabList(Labirinto* m);

void freelist(LabList* head);

/* Creates a Maze and inserts it in the list */
LabList* addLab(LabList* head, LabList* ML, Labirinto* m);

/* Build the maze list from a file */
LabList* readLab(FILE* filePtr, LabList *head);

/* Get a single Maze from a file */
Labirinto* inputLab(FILE* filePtr);

//void showLab(Labirinto* m);

//void printStrArray(int dim, char** strArray, char* name);

/* Terminates if allocation failled */
void checkAllocationError(const void* ptr, const char* errorMsg);

void check_cel (Labirinto *m, FILE *file_out);

#endif
```

And Valgrind output:

```
==82== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==82==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==82==    by 0x1096C4: main (main.c:95)
==82==  Address 0x4a47040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 22 free'd
==82==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==82==    by 0x1096B8: main (main.c:94)
==82==  Block was alloc'd at
==82==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)==82==    by 0x10946E: main (main.c:37)
==82==
==82==
==82== HEAP SUMMARY:
==82==     in use at exit: 470 bytes in 4 blocks
==82==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 7 frees, 6,573 bytes allocated
==82==
==82== 18 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==82==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)==82==    by 0x1094FD: main (main.c:41)
==82==
==82== 452 (16 direct, 436 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==82==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)==82==    by 0x10970F: newLabList (roap.c:29)
==82==    by 0x109767: addLab (roap.c:41)
==82==    by 0x109BDE: readLab (roap.c:144)
==82==    by 0x1095D5: main (main.c:57)
==82==
==82== LEAK SUMMARY:
==82==    definitely lost: 34 bytes in 2 blocks
==82==    indirectly lost: 436 bytes in 2 blocks
==82==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==82==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==82==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Lines:

main.c:37
`file_arg = (char*)calloc(1, strlen(argv[2]) + strlen(extencao_out) + 1);`

main.c:94
`free(filename);`

main.c:95
`free(file_arg);`

main.c:41
`filename = (char*)calloc(1, strlen(file_arg) + strlen(ponto) + 1);`

main.c:57
`head = readLab(filePtr, head);`

roap.c:29
`LabList* newML = calloc(1, sizeof(LabList) );`

roap.c:41
`ML = newLabList(m);`

roap.c:144
`addLab(head, nextLabList, m);`

Any help on solving these errors and mismanagement of memory would be most appreciated.

Comment: "double free" means you tried to free the same pointer twice.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that although you allocate `filename` and `file_arg` separately with calloc, you then reassign `filename` to the return value of `strtok`, passing file_arg. So now `filename` points to the first character of `file_arg`, and so you lose track of the buffer originally assigned to `filename` and free `file_arg` twice.

(This assumes that the first character of `file_arg` is not `'.'`. If it is, then `strtok` returns a pointer to the first character of `file_arg` that is not `'.'`, and trying to free that will also produce a valgrind error.)